# Combine two columns that's are on a column "B" and column "C" and then make them into one column on column "E" with even and odd position each others

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I want to **Combine two columns** that's are on a column "**B**" and column "**C**" and want to make them to be one column like on column "**E**" but in this case I want to make them, replace both of them after ***Combined them as one and then replace they're position to be with an even and odd position each others***. Is it possible to be done ? Look how I explaining this all with the table I've created on down below this and see how I expected that and please feel free also to edit into my sample g.shee doc what I've atteched on down below this.

[THIS HERE YOU CAN EDIT TO MY SAMPLE G.SHEET TO SOLVE THIS MY QUEEZ. THANKS IN ADVANCE!](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6gAkJicW73yRyaixFhhhAUWkPNVxCJ1L4kbuI_KVWI/edit?usp=sharing)

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | **N U M B** | **I D - N A M E** | **I D - C O D E** | **H E L P E R** | **E X P E C T O U T P U T** |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 5 | I7AF9 | J3573 | 2 | I7AF9 |
| 5 |  |  | IYR | 1 | J3573 |
| 6 |  |  | F498S | 3 | IYR |
| 7 |  |  |  |  | F498S |
| 8 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | 4 | H3D90 | C684J | 1 | H3D90 |
| 10 |  |  | J58 | 1 | C684J |
| 11 |  |  |  |  | J58 |
| 12 | 3 | H684K | JF585 | 2 | H684K |
| 13 |  |  |  |  | JF585 |
| 14 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15 | 2 | FJSR | 4684 | 3 | FJSR |
| 16 |  |  |  |  | 4684 |
| 17 | 1 | JSR | 834 | 1 | JSR |
| 18 |  |  | 49 | 2 | 834 |
| 19 |  |  | 9835 | 1 | 49 |
| 20 |  |  |  |  | 9835 |

Comment: =FILTER(FLATTEN(B4:C);FLATTEN(B4:C)<>"") would be the fast answer. But, are you looking for some arrayformula?, it should match the beginning row of each element in B as in your example leaving empty rows?

Comment: Yeah @Martín thanks for the fast reply. Yes, Martin! I need the result exactly the same what I expected it what it's look like at the sample of table on column **E** I also want to include it the (_**blank**_ or _**space**_) as well but not for all (_**blank**_ or _**space**_) are in each their rows of their columns but that's just particular or some random blank or space who maded by auto random data input ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with helper column like:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN({IF(A4:A<>""; "​"; )\ B4:C}); "where Col1 <>''"; ))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that's so very impressive that very really @player0! even weather is'nt effective so much at least that was so close too much at the point because that's still neede it to create the column helper.